# не удаляются куки! Что делать?

Tags: php

Метод delete класса Cookies:

```
public static function delete($key)
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$key])){
        self::set($key, '', -3600);
        unset($_COOKIE[$key]);
    }

}

public static function set($key, $value, $time = 31536000)
{
    setcookie($key, $value, time() + $time, '/');
}
```

класс Cart

```
public function clear()
{
    Cookie::delete('products');
}
```

ну и собственно метод контроллера:

```
public function clear()
{
    $this->cart->clear();
}
```

**Обновление**

```
public static function set($key, $value, $time = 31536000)
{
    setcookie($key, $value, time() + $time, '/');
}
```

так же есть метод deleteProduct в классе Cart
        public function deleteProduct($id)
    {
        $id = (int)$id;

```
    $key = array_search($id, $this->products);
    if($key !== false){
        unset($this->products[$key]);
    }

    Cookie::set('products', serialize($this->products));
    Router::redirect('/products/cart/');
}
```

он тоже не работает, хотя если убрать условие  if($key !== false) он работает. вот это непонятно

Comment: Если не сложно, приведите еще содержимое метода set()

Comment: А в функцию `delete` вообще попадает? или в `set`. Ведь эти слова php использует для неких нужд..может быть конфликт происходит......покажите метод `set`

Comment: @Ivan Skald Судя по вашим функциям - все работает штатно. Причиной может быть только одна: у вас наверняка высвечивается ошибка `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`, которую вы не видите, потому что у вас не включено отображение ошибок и предупреждений `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`